# save image to sdcard android Directory problem

Tags: android

Im trying to save data to sdCard first i tried to saave it privately within app directory on externalStorage using getExternalFilesDir but gives me nullPointerException so i tried the other way given below it worked but when i want to store files into a custom directory that i want to named myself it give me error:

```
FileOutputStream os;
dirName = "/mydirectory/";
        try {  
            if (android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageState().equals(
                    android.os.Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED)){
                File sdCard = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
                File dir = new File (sdCard.getAbsolutePath() + dirName);
                dir.mkdirs();
                //File file = new File(this.getExternalFilesDir(null), this.dirName+fileName); //this function give null pointer exception so im using other one
                File file = new File(dir, dirName+fileName);
                os = new FileOutputStream(file);
            }else{
                os = context.openFileOutput(fileName, MODE_PRIVATE);
            }
            resizedBitmap.compress(CompressFormat.PNG, 100, os);
            os.flush();
            os.close();
        }catch(Exception e){

        }
```

**ErrorLog:**

java.io.FileNotFoundException: /mnt/sdcard/mvc/mvc/myfile2.png (No such file or directory)

Comment: Try logging the parameters you are passing to all of the file and directory calls - likely you aren't doing what you think you are.  Also check all of the return values so you know if one didn't work.

Comment: Do you have the full stacktrace?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your directory "/mnt/sdcard/mvc/mvc" may not exist. What about changing your path to store the image in the `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()` path and then working from there?

Also, as Robert pointed out, make sure you have [write permission to external storage](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html#WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) in your manifest.

**Edit** - to create directories:

```
String root = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();
new File(root + "/mvc/mvc").mkdirs();
```

Then you can save a file to `root + "/mvc/mvc/foo.png"`.

Comment: when i store it directly on the root like as you said above it works fine but i want to create a directory and named it "image" and store the images in it

Comment: I added info about creating directories

Comment: String root = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+this.dirName;
 new File(root).mkdirs();
 File file = new File(root , fileName);
 os = new FileOutputStream(file);            Bitmap.compress(CompressFormat.PNG, 80, os);
            os.flush();
            os.close();

Answer (score 5):

Have you requested permission to write onto SD card? Add the following string to you app manifest:

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You should check if you have added the required permission `android.permission-group.STORAGE` to your app. Without that permission you won't be able to access anything on the SD-Card.

BTW: On the Android system I know the SD-card is mounted on `/sdcard` not `/mnt/sdcard`

Comment: Yup i have included the permission and the i have checked file explorer(ddms) it shows /mnt/sdcard/ but the problem is same. But now im getting this error when i change my line to this File file = new File(dir, dirName);

Comment: Error: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /mnt/sdcard/mydirectory/myfile2.png (Is a directory)

Answer (score 0):

I found this book to be very helpful: "Pro Android Media: Developing Graphics, Music, Video, and Rich Media Apps for Smartphones and Tablets". I noticed a part that allows saving images and stuff to the SD card.

Comment: Well that will be nice if you just send me some sample pages ill have a look and think about buying it if found useful. Thanks, you'll find my email address in my profile

Comment: can't seem to find your email addy in your profile? If u can see mine drop me a message and I'll reply! :)