# How to store images into local database on Android

Tags: android

In my app, one issue is there. I am downloading the images from the web and these images are stored in the local database. How do I store these images into the local database?

Comment: Save on SD CARD

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5196330/save-image-to-sdcard-android-directory-problem

Comment: for sdcard, i am getting the out of memory exception

Comment: Then it's a bad sign for your DB also since you said you'll have a lot of images and the sdcard is more likely to have more capacity than the device itself.

Comment: SD Card can hold data in GB .. Whats the size of images you are downloading and storing.

Comment: previously i am storing the images in the sd card when the retrival time i am getting the out of memory exception .please refer this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7385139/android-out-of-memory-problem.

Answer (score 0):

you can do that by several ways, either stored it as BLOB or stored the path of image 
nice example **[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6815355/how-to-store-image-retreived-from-url-in-a-sqlite-database/6815819#6815819)**

Comment: here where u r storing the dowloaded images into DB. Here u r return drawable then how to store this drawable in db?

Comment: on the same link see my below answer

Comment: what is the local db size? because i have to lot of images/

Comment: here is any chance of getting out of memory exception?

Comment: depends, now device are coming with larger memory so there is less chance

Answer (score 0):

To store an image in the database, your table creation should be:

```
db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE Funny(picid TEXT,myimage BLOB,gender TEXT,country TEXT)");
```

The image type is blob.

Convert an image [URL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_Resource_Locator) into bytes form as shown below:

```
URL url = null;
try {
    url = new URL(YOUR IMAGE URL);
}
catch (MalformedURLException e2) {
    e2.printStackTrace();
}

URLConnection ucon = null;
try {
    ucon = url.openConnection();
}
catch (IOException e1) {
    e1.printStackTrace();
}

InputStream is = null;
try {
    is = ucon.getInputStream();
}
catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(is,128);
ByteArrayBuffer baf = new ByteArrayBuffer(128);

int current = 0;
try {
    while ((current = bis.read()) != -1) {
        baf.append((byte) current);
    }
}
catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
bb = baf.toByteArray();
help.insert(picid[0],bb, gender1[0], country1[0]);
```

And insert statement is:

```
public void insert(String string,byte[] bytes, String gender, String country) {
    ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
    cv.put("picid", string);
    cv.put("myimage", bytes);
    cv.put("gender", gender);
    cv.put("country", country);
    getWritableDatabase().insert("Funny","gender", cv);
    Log.e("inserted", "inserted");
}
```

I hope this helps you.

Comment: here is any chance of getting out of memory exception. because in my lot of images are there

Comment: it is better to decrease the size of your images

Comment: how to create table? please send the syntax

Comment: see in my answer above db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE Funny

Comment: i am asking about creating db ref variable. here u r using db. what is db?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/3396/discussion-between-naresh-and-abhi)

Answer (score 0):

I would rather store the image files inside a cache folder and store only the path inside your local DB since it will allow your application to be more scalable and not to overload your DB.

You can use this path to cache your images:

```
File dataPath = new File(Environment.getDataDirectory(), yourPackageName);
```

See here [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Environment.html#getDataDirectory%28%29).

Answer (score 0):

Images can be stored as a bytearray to the database. You can get it from a nice example from the following tutorial about how to store and retrieve image from a database.

[Here is the tutorial for image store in a database](http://www.helloandroid.com/tutorials/store-imagesfiles-database)