# android null pointer error

Tags: java, android, eclipse, nullpointerexception

hi i try get file name from external stroge but i have an error where is problem?

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

//protected ContextWrapper context;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Button test=(Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    test.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            //ContextWrapper context = new ContextWrapper();
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        //  File datapath = Environment.getDataDirectory();
            //File cacheDir = new File(context.getCacheDir(),"tempfile");
            String extState = new String();
            extState=Environment.getExternalStorageState();
            //File amcuk=Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
            //String externalname=new String();
            //String internalname=new String();
            //you may also want to add (...|| Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED_READ_ONLY)
            //if you are only interested in reading the filesystem
            //try {
            String name=new String();
                if(!extState.equals(Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED)) {
                    //handle error here
                    Log.d("ss", "sad");}
                else {
                    //File f=new File(extState);
                    Log.d("www", "www");
                    Log.d("wwwaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa", "wwwaaaaaaaaaaaaa");
                    File sdCardRoot = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
                    File yourDir = new File(sdCardRoot, "yourpath");
                    for (File f : yourDir.listFiles()) {
                        if (f.isFile()){
                             name = f.getName();
                            }
                            // make something with the name
                    }
            }// catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO: handle exception
                //Log.d("sasd", "sad");*/
            //}

            Log.d("dosya adları", extState);
            //File mydataDir =new File(path,"path");



            //Log.d("dosya adları internal", internalname);
        }
    });

}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

}
```

add manifest.xml permissions

```
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

ddms log message is

```
08-24 16:54:38.986: E/AndroidRuntime(2629): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-24 16:54:38.986: E/AndroidRuntime(2629): java.lang.NullPointerException
08-24 16:54:38.986: E/AndroidRuntime(2629):     at com.example.fileexplorear.MainActivity$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:55)
08-24 16:54:38.986: E/AndroidRuntime(2629):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2461)
08-24 16:54:38.986: E/AndroidRuntime(2629):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:8890)
08-24 16:54:38.986: E/AndroidRuntime(2629):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
08-24 16:54:38.986: E/AndroidRuntime(2629):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
08-24 16:54:38.986: E/AndroidRuntime(2629):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
08-24 16:54:38.986: E/AndroidRuntime(2629):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4632)
08-24 16:54:38.986: E/AndroidRuntime(2629):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-24 16:54:38.986: E/AndroidRuntime(2629):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
08-24 16:54:38.986: E/AndroidRuntime(2629):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:858)
08-24 16:54:38.986: E/AndroidRuntime(2629):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
08-24 16:54:38.986: E/AndroidRuntime(2629):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

my 55 line is

```
                        for (File f : yourDir.listFiles()) {
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only possible explanation I can see is that `listFiles()` is returning null.

From [the docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/File.html#listFiles%28%29):

> Returns an array of files contained in the directory represented by
>   this file. The result is *null* if this file is not a directory. The
>   paths of the files in the array are absolute if the path of this file
>   is absolute, they are relative otherwise.
>
> **Returns**
>
> an array of files or null.

So, your file is not a directory.

You could try creating your file using only a string parameter to the dir instead

(and skip your `"yourpath"` parameter):

```
String sdCardRoot = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();
    File yourDir = new File( root_sd ) ;       
    File list[] = yourDir.listFiles();
```

which [constructs a new file using the specified path](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/File.html#File%28java.lang.String%29).

Comment: thanks its works but write only one file name where is other?h

Comment: @amra Not sure. Are you 100% positive it's in the directory you're listing?

Comment: @Keyser I m not sure  because i print file only this message shown [Ljava.io.File;@47f42770

Comment: @amra That looks like the hashcode of a File object. Try using the file's `toString()` or `getName()` method.

Comment: @Keyser problem is listFiles method only main directory  files return,dont under another path in main path

Comment: @amra Did you use my code? If so, you might want to specify another path than `sdCardRoot` like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5196428/645270). There are more examples here on SO if you search for stuff like `list files directory android`