# How to Save and Share an Image of Viewpager?

Tags: android, android-viewpager

I want to save and share Image of Viewpager

I've done these till now, but yet I can't share / save images

## ImageAdapter

```
public class ImageAdapter extends PagerAdapter {
Context context;
private int[] GalImages = new int[] {       
R.drawable.pic_1,
R.drawable.pic_2,
R.drawable.pic_3
.
.
.
};
ImageAdapter(Context context){
this.context=context;
}
@Override
public int getCount() {
return GalImages.length;
}
@Override
public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
return view == ((ImageView) object);
}
@Override
public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {
ImageView imageView = new ImageView(context);
imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_INSIDE);
imageView.setImageResource(GalImages[position]);
((ViewPager) container).addView(imageView, 0);
return imageView;
}
@Override
public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
((ViewPager) container).removeView((ImageView) object);
}
}
```

## MainAcitivtiy Class

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {


Bitmap bm;
String extStorageDirectory;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.view_pager);
ImageAdapter adapter = new ImageAdapter(this);
viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);




extStorageDirectory = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();
}


public void share(View v){
    Intent share = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    share.setType("image/*");
ByteArrayOutputStream bytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

bm.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, bytes);
    File f = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + File.separator+ "temporary_file.jpg");

    try {
        f.createNewFile();
        FileOutputStream fo = new FileOutputStream(f);
        fo.write(bytes.toByteArray());
    } catch (IOException e) {                       
            e.printStackTrace();
    }
    share.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.parse("file:///sdcard/temporary_file.jpg"));
    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(share, "Share Image"));


    }

public void save (View v){

      ByteArrayOutputStream bytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        FileOutputStream outp = null;
        File filename;
        try {
            String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath()+Nameoffolder;

            new File(path + "/folder/subfolder").mkdirs();
            filename = new File(path + "/folder/subfolder/image.jpg");

            FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(filename);
            out.write(bytes.toByteArray());

            bm.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 90, out);
            out.flush();
            out.close();

            MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(getContentResolver(), filename.getAbsolutePath(), filename.getName(), filename.getName());

            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), " Saved " , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

              }  


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

}
```

## XML file

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
android:id="@+id/view_pager"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="0dp"
android:layout_weight="1"
android:layout_alignParentTop="true" 
/>

<Button
android:id="@+id/button1"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/view_pager"
android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/view_pager"
android:layout_marginBottom="29dp"
android:text="@string/save"
android:onClick="save" />

<Button
android:id="@+id/button2"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/button1"
android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/button1"
android:layout_alignRight="@+id/view_pager"
android:text="@string/share"
android:onClick="share" />


</RelativeLayout>
```

It would be great if anybody could help me 
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Regarding how to share [this](http://developer.android.com/training/sharing/send.html) link will you and regarding saving an image on to sdcard [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5196330/save-image-to-sdcard-android-directory-problem) link will help you in solving your problem.

Edit:

Write your sharing and saving code in pager fragment( In the fragment Itself).  Let say you have written methods saveImage() and shareImage() in your fragment

Now get your current fragment in activity as

YourPagerFrament fr = (YourPagerFrament ) yourPagerAdapter.instantiateItem(pager, pager.getCurrentItem());

and now call your methods from fragment as

fr.saveImage();
fr.shareImage();

Hope you understand now

Comment: thanks but it doesnt help how to do it with viewpager

Comment: thanks mr Rashmi for ur help but i dont understand i hv lost the track.